# PHP move_uploaded_file, what security does it provide

Tags: php, file-upload

Wherever I look on the difference between PHP functions' `rename` and `move_uploaded_file` it always says that the difference is that `move_uploaded_file` have some security features.

My questions are:

1. what are those security features, what happen if I don't use it?
2. In case that I can't use it (I did an upload but not through POST) so I have to use the `rename` function, what security measures do I need to take?

Thanks.

**Edit**
@Pekka asked from me to elaborate of how I plan to upload the file.
I'm going to upload files through Ajax, and I have some queue feature for uploading multiples files. Therefore I'm using the `php://input` stream.

If I understand Pekka answer correctly, I have nothing to worry about since I'm getting the file as a stream and I'm not copying any temp file.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you expand on the case where you can't use it? If you're not doing a POST upload, you can't use PHP's built-in `$_FILES` array and there would not be a temporary file to rename, would there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The background of this was an ancient, pretty bad vulnerability (in the early 2000s) in which you, instead of uploading an actual file, you could overwrite the `tmp_file` path with a local file path, leading to that local file being treated as the upload instead of the real uploaded file. (There was no `$_FILES` array back then.)

So for example, when uploading an avatar, the script would `copy()` the system file you specified (say, a configuration file `../../super_secret/config.php` or a `.htpasswd`) to a public location and try to display it as the avatar image in a `<img>` tag.

Strangely, I'm unable to find any specific info on this vulnerability (I've searched a number of times already over the past couple of years), but I know for a fact it existed because I tested it myself. Any links are welcome.

As to what security measures to take, as said in the comment, I think you need to explain in more detail what kind of alternative file upload you are planning to use.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I elaborated my question as you asked, please let me know if my conclusion is right, thanks.
I would +1 the answer if I had reputation for it.

Comment: After accepting your answer I got enough reputation to +1 your answer

Comment: @goBeepit heh, nice coincidence :) yeah, if you use `php://input` directly and don't rely on user input for the file name, you shouldn't have anything to worry about in this regard.

Comment: Thanks, my research ends here